# How to add an array to a laravel collection object item

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to add array to a laravel object with `->push` on the object however it is not working. What do I appear to be doing wrong? The object is unchanged.

```
   $cottages = Cottage::all();

    foreach ($cottages as $cottage) {

        //returns array
        $gallery = $this->getCottageGallery($cottage['folder']);
        //should append to $cottage object
        $cottage->push($gallery);
    }

   dump($cottages);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just used the `$cottage->setAttribute('gallery', $gallery);` to assign it to the object!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly in the collection getting rid of the `foreach`statement:

```
$cottages = Cottage::all()->map(function ($cottage){
             $cottage->setAttribute('gallery', $this->getCottageGallery($cottage['folder']);

            return $cottage;
        });
```